# Drawing image in Objective-C

Tags: ios, xcode, drawimage

I need to draw an image with custom sides (see attached file).

[image: Custom image]

I tried to do this with Baziels but I dont know that is good way to do this.

Comment: coregraphics + [uibazierpath](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html) + CGContextClipToMask

Comment: What the heck is a Baziel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If below things can help. This will take lot of modification but it will help you in some way.

> Use a `UIView` subclass.
>
> Give intended frame to that subclass.
>
> Add Imageview on that `UIView`.
>
> Use clear color as your `UIView's` background color.
>
> Use and modify below code in `drawrect` of that subview.
>
> Don't forget to call setneedsdisplay every time you make change inside drawrect method.

(Do NOT take below code as complete solution.. This is just example of what you need to use in such task.)

```
 - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    
    
    CGContextRef aRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    
    // If you have content to draw after the shape,
    // save the current state before changing the transform.
    //CGContextSaveGState(aRef);
    
    // Adjust the view's origin temporarily. The oval is
    // now drawn relative to the new origin point.
    
    CGContextTranslateCTM(aRef, _leftMargin, 0);
    
    // Create an cache progress shape to draw.
    UIBezierPath *aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    
    // Set the render colors.
    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    [[UIColor grayColor] setFill];
    
    // Adjust the drawing options as needed.
    aPath.lineWidth = 0;
    
    // Set the starting point of the shape.
    [aPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, _height)];
    
    // Draw the lines.
    [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0)];
    [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(_width, 0.0)];
    [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(_width, _height)];
    [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(_width/2, _height - _traingleHeight)];
    [aPath closePath];
    
    // Fill the path before stroking it so that the fill
    // color does not obscure the stroked line.
    [aPath fill];
    [aPath stroke];

    float lowerdrawing = ((_traingleHeight / _height) * 100);
    ////NSLog(@"lowerdrawing = %f", lowerdrawing);

    //NSLog(@"percent = %f", _percent);
    float percentage = _percent / 100;
    
    if (_percent <= lowerdrawing) {
        
        [self calculateNewWidthHeight];
        
        // draw left traingle upto 26 %
        
        // Create an oval shape to draw.
        UIBezierPath *aPath2 = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
        
        // Set the render colors.
        [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
        [[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"]] setFill];
        
        // Adjust the drawing options as needed.
        aPath2.lineWidth = 0;
        
        // Set the starting point of the shape.
        [aPath2 moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, _height)];
        
        // Draw the lines.
        
        [aPath2 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0.0 , _height -  (percentage * _height) )];
        [aPath2 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake( _newWidth , _height -  (percentage * _height)) ];
        [aPath2 closePath];
        
        // Fill the path before stroking it so that the fill
        // color does not obscure the stroked line.
        [aPath2 fill];
        [aPath2 stroke];
        
    
        
        // draw right traingle upto 26 %
        
        // Create an oval shape to draw.
        UIBezierPath *aPath3 = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
        
        // Set the render colors.
        [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
        [[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"]] setFill];
        
        
        // Adjust the drawing options as needed.
        aPath3.lineWidth = 0;
        
        // Set the starting point of the shape.
        [aPath3 moveToPoint:CGPointMake( _width, _height )];
        
        // Draw the lines.
        [aPath3 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake( _width, _height -  (percentage * _height) )];
        [aPath3 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake( _width - _newWidth  , _height -  (percentage * _height) )];
        [aPath3 closePath];
        
        // Fill the path before stroking it so that the fill
        // color does not obscure the stroked line.
        [aPath3 fill];
        [aPath3 stroke];
        
    }
    else if (_percent <= 100 ) {
        
        // Create an cache progress shape to draw.
        UIBezierPath *aPath4 = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
        
        // Set the render colors.
        [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
        [[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"]] setFill];
        
        
        // Adjust the drawing options as needed.
        aPath4.lineWidth = 0;
        
        // Set the starting point of the shape.
        [aPath4 moveToPoint:CGPointMake( 0.0, _height )];
        
        // Draw the lines.
        
        [aPath4 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake( 0.0, _height - (percentage * _height) )];
        [aPath4 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake( _width , _height - (percentage * _height) )];
        [aPath4 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake( _width, _height )];
        [aPath4 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake( (_width/2), (_height - _traingleHeight) )];
        [aPath4 closePath];
        
        // Fill the path before stroking it so that the fill
        // color does not obscure the stroked line.
        [aPath4 fill];
        [aPath4 stroke];
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for hint. Now I can understand how to create custom shapes with images as background :)